# How can i add styles to newElement.Innerhtml provided below

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add the text styles into the **newElement.InnerHTML** part into the below javascript. The **5th line** into the javascript says **"You can download the file in 10 seconds"** part. I want to add styles to this text like making this text bigger as well as text colors.

(I am currently trying in WordPress)

I am a beginner and want help with this Thanks..

Javascript code -

```js
var downloadButton = document.getElementById("download");
var counter = 10;
var newElement = document.createElement("p");
newElement.innerHTML = "You can download the file in 10 seconds.";
var id;
downloadButton.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, downloadButton);
id = setInterval(function() {
counter--;
if(counter < 0) {
newElement.parentNode.replaceChild(downloadButton, newElement);
clearInterval(id);
} else {
newElement.innerHTML = "You can download the file in " + counter.toString() + " seconds.";
}}, 1000);
```

```html
<button id="download">download</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `newElement.style.propertyName = "value";`
For example, if you wish to make the text bigger you do
`newElement.style.fontSize = "50px";`

And if you want to change the color you do `newElement.style.color = "red";`

This works but it will be very difficult to maintain, I would recommend you adding a css class to the element, by doing this you can set all your styles in the css class instead of the js.

`newElement.classList.add("css-class-you-want-to-name");`

Then you just create a simple css class

```
.css-class-you-want-to-name { 
  font-size: 50px;
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I gotta try this, also if I add a CSS class to the element to make it easy, the javascript will not break right? will it work correctly

Comment: yes it'll work just fine, if you inspect element when is on the screen you will see the element you create has class="css-class-you-want-to-name", thats all its doing

Comment: oh alright okayy the last question but little dumb xD, where can i add this code  **newElement.classList.add("css-class-you-want-to-name");** ? shoud i add this intothe javascript?

Comment: after the line `var newElement = document.createElement("p");  ... `

Comment: well, that's worked!! thanks, man, I was literally confused with the codes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do like this.

```js
var downloadButton = document.getElementById("download");
var counter = 10;
var newElement = document.createElement("p");
newElement.innerHTML = "You can download the file in 10 seconds.";
newElement.style.color = "red";
newElement.style.fontSize = "20px";
var id;
downloadButton.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, downloadButton);
id = setInterval(function() {
counter--;
if(counter < 0) {
newElement.parentNode.replaceChild(downloadButton, newElement);
clearInterval(id);
} else {
newElement.innerHTML = "You can download the file in " + counter.toString() + " seconds.";
}}, 1000);
```

```html
<button id="download">download</button>
```